# AJAX to Web Service Design: Request for Commentary

Tags: java, ajax, web-services

I am designing a Java web application that makes heavy use of AJAX (for user experience - no reloads, etc.). I also have the need to expose a large number of web services because there will be many different clients (not just web browsers) connecting to the Java EE backend.

This got me thinking that it might just make sense for my AJAX XmlHttpRequests to somehow (magically) envelope a SOAP message and talk directly with my existing web servers, so I'm not writing duplicate code.  Although I don't really know how I'll do that at this point, I know its possible because I've already found a few articles on doing just that.

I'm not concerned with whether or not I *can* have AJAX content post to a Java web service; I'm concerned with whether or not I *should* be doing this.

Is this a discouraged practice? Are there security vulnerabilities or performance issues I need to be aware of? It makes sense to do this from a reusability and system consistency point of view, but I'm neither an AJAX or Java EE expert to know any better here.

I guess I'm just interested in some educated opinions. And, as always, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are definitely on the right track: try to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and reuse your code wherever it is sensible. Your approach is - in my opinion - very good, so I just have a few remarks to maybe point you in the direction you would like to go anyway.

In my humble opinion, especially when you are dealing with AJAX, Json would be a much handier format for your data: your AJAX code can directly work with the supplied data structures, you save *a lot* of data overhead (especially if you are considering using the services a lot) and - but that is very subjective - Json is a much more elegant data format.

I don't know what your other clients expect from your webservices, but if you are not fixed on the format of the messages being transmitted (although you did mention SOAP and XML), they could consume and produce Json, too.

A very handy framework to produce and consume Json is [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), if you are just looking into parsing and creating Json, I really like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) from Google.

I would suggest you look into [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) webservices, especially when combined with [Java EE](http://blogs.sphinx.at/java/jee6-rest-restful-web-services-using-glassfish-3-1-and-jersey/). If you are working with a Java EE 6 compliant server, creating RESTful webservices is very easy. They even can produce and consume different kinds of data formats - Json and XML for example.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks LeChe - awesome answer! I'll award the bounty to you as soon as SO permits.

Comment: Glad I could help. It would be nice if you could edit your post eventually to let us know how you ended up implementing your services: I am always interested to learn some more. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can design your code such that every call to the backend is through a webservice(soap or rest.. that will your decision .. however nowadays things are made in rest).

As regards security, your webserice can be exposed via oauth calls.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with oauth - I'll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

From the post, I understand that you have a lot of web service already available.Now you want to design a new web application based on this.So that you can re use them.

In that scenario you have to consider one important thing.If all these web services are hosted in different servers,then you will ended up with cross site scripting problem.You cannot communicate to different servers by using ajax.So if all these web services are come 
under a single server then you can consider to write a new web application using spring 3.0.Which is the most flexible framework available to build java web applications.

```
I think  you need a GUI rich application.If so my personal pick is to use GWT.I mean to write your client side using GWT.It will gave you full browser compatibility.My suggestion is like this,Build a client side using GWT and you can call server asynchronously by its built in support.Then from server you can communicate any other web service and gave back the necessary data.
```

Hope this will help you !!!!!!!!

Comment: Although I like the suggestions from Pipalayan and LeChe, I'll definitely look into the GWT to see what it offers. Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question!